# Unsufficient permissions for running '.jar' file as root

Tags: java, jar, user-permissions

I need to run a 64-bit version software for business purposes but I'm having a hard time doing it. The software is distributed officially by the government and its 64-bit version is only available for Linux as a '.jar' executable. My problem is that, when I run the '.jar' file, the program warns about unsufficient user permissions for running the software. As a workaround, I've tried running it as root, applying 'chmod 777 -R folderpath'... but it returns the same error message about unsufficient user permissions.

I've done a dive deep into the code and it seems that the program tries to modify its own '.jar' file  during runtime. In that way, I don't know how to grant full user access for the files/folders that are inside the executable. Do you know how to help ?

Tks a lot

Edit1: The '.jar' filepath is /root/ProgramasSPED/EFDContribuicoes/efdcontribuicoes.jar'

The ls -l /root/ProgrmasSPED output is:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  540 jul 21 16:37 Desinstalar-EFDContribuições.desktop
drwsrwsrwt 8 root root 4096 jul 22 17:27 EFDContribuicoes
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  673 jul 21 16:37 EFD-Contribuições.desktop
```

The contents of the folder where the executable is are:

```
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root    4096 jul 21 16:37 Ajuda
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root    4096 jul 21 16:37 configuracoes
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 1010685 abr  6 08:04 efdcontribuicoes.jar
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   15636 jul 21 16:37 IzPackLocaleEnabledXdgDesktopIconScript.sh
drwxrwxrwx  6 root root    4096 jul 21 16:37 jre
drwxrwxrwx 51 root root    4096 jul 21 16:37 lib
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root  201037 abr  6 08:04 lixeira.ico
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   21662 abr  6 08:04 logo.ico
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root    4096 jul 21 16:37 recursos
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root    4096 jul 21 16:37 Uninstaller
```

The contents of the executable '.jar' file is:
As you can see, I still have rw permissions for all files, altough I can't change my permissions during runtime

```
root@ribel-VirtualBox:/usr/bin/jre/bin# ls -l /root/Desktop/myJar
total 64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2224 abr  6 08:03 aplicacao.properties
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 abr  6 08:03 arvore
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 abr  6 08:03 br
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  199 abr  6 08:03 build.properties
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 abr  6 08:03 icones
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  279 abr  6 08:03 Mensagens.properties
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 abr  6 08:04 META-INF
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1192 abr  6 08:03 ppgd-default.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6450 abr  6 08:03 ppgdmenubar.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4250 abr  6 08:03 ppgdtoolbar.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 9473 abr  6 08:03 Recursos.properties
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 abr  6 08:03 relatorios
```

The uncompiled code is:

```
package br.gov.serpro.sped.piscofinspva.fronteira.init;

import br.gov.serpro.comum.arquivo.Arquivo;
import br.gov.serpro.comum.progresso.excecao.ExcecaoProcessoInterrompido;
import br.gov.serpro.comum.swing.exibirmensagem.ExibirMensagem;
import br.gov.serpro.comum.swing.progresso.DialogAguarde;
import br.gov.serpro.comum.util.UtilSO;
import br.gov.serpro.sped.piscofinspva.edicao.escrituracao.controle.ControleEditarEscrituracao;
import br.gov.serpro.sped.piscofinspva.edicao.escrituracao.controle.IControleEditarEscrituracao;
import br.gov.serpro.sped.piscofinspva.fronteira.escrituracao.abrir.ControleAbrirEscrituracao;
import br.gov.serpro.sped.piscofinspva.fronteira.escrituracao.abrir.IControleAbrirEscrituracao;
import br.gov.serpro.sped.piscofinspva.fronteira.tratarexcecao.TratadorExcecaoFronteira;
import br.gov.serpro.sped.piscofinspva.infra.mensagem.MensagensSistema;
import br.gov.serpro.sped.piscofinspva.infra.versao.controle.FabricaControle;
import br.gov.serpro.sped.piscofinspva.nucleo.init.InicializacaoSistema;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.channels.FileLock;
import serpro.ppgd.infraestrutura.PlataformaPPGD;

public class InicializacaoFronteira {
  private static InicializacaoFronteira singleton;
  
  public static InicializacaoFronteira getSingleton() {
    if (singleton == null)
      singleton = new InicializacaoFronteira(); 
    return singleton;
  }
  
  public void inicializar() {
    try {
      configurarServicosDaFronteira();
      verificarPreCondicoes();
      DialogAguarde janelaAguarde = DialogAguarde.getNewDialogAguarde(
          PlataformaPPGD.getPlataforma().getJanelaPrincipal(), "AGUARDE_INICIALIZAR_SISTEMA", 
          
          InicializacaoSistema.getSingleton(), new Object[0]);
      janelaAguarde.iniciar();
    } catch (ExcecaoProcessoInterrompido e) {
      TratadorExcecaoFronteira.getSingleton().tratarExcecao((Throwable)e);
    } 
  }
  
  private void configurarServicosDaFronteira() {
    FabricaControle.getSingleton().adicionarInterfaceServico(IControleAbrirEscrituracao.class);
    FabricaControle.getSingleton().adicionarVersaoServico(ControleAbrirEscrituracao.class);
    FabricaControle.getSingleton().adicionarInterfaceServico(IControleEditarEscrituracao.class);
    FabricaControle.getSingleton().adicionarVersaoServico(ControleEditarEscrituracao.class);
  }
  
  
  private static void verificarPreCondicoes() {
    if (isProgramaExecutandoMesmoUsuario()) {
      ExibirMensagem.obterUnicaInstancia().exibirMensagemAviso("Uma instanterior da aplicaestem execu);
      System.exit(1);
    } 
    if (isProgramaExecutandoOutroUsuario()) {
      ExibirMensagem.obterUnicaInstancia().exibirMensagemAviso("Uma instanterior da aplicaestem execupor algum outro usu);
      System.exit(1);
    } 
    if (!verificarPermissaoEscrita()) {
      ExibirMensagem.obterUnicaInstancia().exibirMensagemAviso(MensagensSistema.MSG_USUARIO_PERMISSAO_ESCRITA
          .getMensagem());
      System.exit(1);
    } 
    if (UtilSO.isWindowsVista()) {
      String versaoJavaUsuario = System.getProperty("java.version");
      if (versaoJavaUsuario.compareTo("1.6.0") < 0) {
        ExibirMensagem.obterUnicaInstancia().exibirMensagemErro(
            String.format(MensagensSistema.MSG_WINDOWS_VISTA.getMensagem(), new Object[] { versaoJavaUsuario }));
        System.exit(1);
      } 
    } 
  }
  
  private static boolean verificarPermissaoEscrita() {
    boolean isArquivoOk = false;
    boolean isPastaOk = false;
    Arquivo arquivo = new Arquivo("controle");
    try {
      isArquivoOk = arquivo.podeEscrever();
    } finally {
      arquivo.delete();
    } 
    try {
      isPastaOk = arquivo.mkdirs();
    } finally {
      isPastaOk &= arquivo.delete();
    } 
    return (isArquivoOk && isPastaOk);
  }
  
  private static boolean isProgramaExecutandoMesmoUsuario() {
    String diretorioHome = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + ".spedpiscofins" + File.separator;
    (new File(diretorioHome)).mkdirs();
    return !travarArquivo(diretorioHome + "TryLock.txt");
  }
  
  private static boolean isProgramaExecutandoOutroUsuario() {
    return !travarArquivo("configuracoes/TryLock.txt");
  }
  
  private static boolean travarArquivo(String arquivo) {
    boolean travado = false;
    FileLock lock = null;
    try {
      RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(arquivo, "rw");
      lock = raf.getChannel().tryLock();
      travado = (lock != null);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      ExibirMensagem.obterUnicaInstancia().exibirMensagemAviso(MensagensSistema.MSG_USUARIO_PERMISSAO_ESCRITA
          .getMensagem());
      System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      TratadorExcecaoFronteira.getSingleton().tratarExcecao(e);
    } 
    return travado;
  }
}
```

And the compiled code of 'VerificarPermissaoEscrita' (it literally means 'CheckWritePermission' is:

```
iconst_0
istore_0
iconst_0
istore_1
new br/gov/serpro/comum/arquivo/Arquivo
dup
ldc "controle"
invokespecial br/gov/serpro/comum/arquivo/Arquivo/<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V
astore_2
aload_2
invokevirtual br/gov/serpro/comum/arquivo/Arquivo/podeEscrever()Z
istore_0
aload_2
invokevirtual br/gov/serpro/comum/arquivo/Arquivo/delete()Z
pop
goto 23
astore_3
aload_2
invokevirtual br/gov/serpro/comum/arquivo/Arquivo/delete()Z
pop
aload_3
athrow
aload_2
invokevirtual br/gov/serpro/comum/arquivo/Arquivo/mkdirs()Z
istore_1
iload_1
aload_2
invokevirtual br/gov/serpro/comum/arquivo/Arquivo/delete()Z
iand
istore_1
goto 40
astore 4
iload_1
aload_2
invokevirtual br/gov/serpro/comum/arquivo/Arquivo/delete()Z
iand
istore_1
aload 4
athrow
iload_0
ifeq 46
iload_1
ifeq 46
iconst_1
goto 47
iconst_0
ireturn
```

Edit2: The problem is located on:

```
 
  private static boolean verificarPermissaoEscrita() {
    boolean isArquivoOk = false;
    boolean isPastaOk = false;
    Arquivo arquivo = new Arquivo("controle");
    try {
      isArquivoOk = arquivo.podeEscrever();
    } finally {
      arquivo.delete();
    } 
    try {
      isPastaOk = arquivo.mkdirs();
    } finally {
      isPastaOk &= arquivo.delete();
    } 
    return (isArquivoOk && isPastaOk);
  }
```

Edit3: I was able to run the program changing the 'br/gov/serpro/comum/arquivo/Arquivo' path to '/root/ProgramasSPED/EFDContribuicoes/ but then the program throws error exceptions because it can't create a database...

Comment: Can you share the error you are getting? Can you share the directory you are running it in?

Comment: I'm running it on '/root/ProgramasSPED/EFDContribuicoes' . The file's name is 'efdcontribuicoes.jar' . Regarding the error message, is a message box written in Portuguese warning about insufficient user permissions; I can provide that but I'm not really sure it will be helpful.